# Export 3D lines with colour interpolation

Tags: graphics3d, export

I have some 3D graphics consisting of lines, with their colours interpolating between values given at each vertex:

```
Graphics3D[{
    AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, -1}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
}]
```

[image]

I am looking to make these graphics accessible to people who do not have Mathematica. The requirement is to have *rotatable* 3D graphics. I am looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this.

---

Here are the things I tried so far:

The obvious thing to do is to export to a common 3D format which my collaborators could look at with some free viewer. However, as far as I can tell, Mathematica won't export colours to the 3D formats it supports. Did I miss anything, is there a format that supports colour and Mathematica can export it? *Note:* If you experiment with this, be aware that `ExportString` and `Export` may produce radically different outputs for some 3D formats.

Another idea is to try to write my own exporter that preserves colour. First, we need to choose the format to export to. I was unable to find a *simple* format that supports edge/line colours, though, especially colour interpolation. Most support colour only for faces, not edges or vertices. Did I miss any appropriate format?

We could convert the graphics to use surfaces instead of lines by replacing `Line` with `Tube`. `Tube` supports colour interpolation as well. But writing a custom exporter for `Tube` is much harder than for lines, unless there is a way to discretize the tubes into polygons *while preserving colour*. Is there a way to do this within Mathematica? `DiscretizeGraphics` creates a `MeshRegion`, so colour information is lost.

Comment: *I am looking to make these graphics accessible to people who do not have Mathematica.* Have you considered publishing it to Wolfram Cloud and making the document public? Then anyone with a browser can access it and use the integrated 3D viewer :)

Comment: @Domen Yes, I tried this, but the performance is really bad (initial load is slow) and the colours don't show while rotating. It's not practically usable. Of course, ideally the visualization would run in a browser so that people don't need a specialized viewer. But that would have been too much to ask for this question.